# Flat Rate Base Price set by product entity field

Tags: commerce

I have a question that has to do with Drupal Commerce's Flat Rate.  I have been going through the information that I could find about how to solve this but could not find a definite solution and I am not very familiar with rules.

The way I want to set up shipping is like this. I have an entity type (variant) which has 2 fields field_shipping_price ( for a shipping price) and also a field field_shipping_quantity_limit (for quantity limit).  How I need this to work is a site user (with the right permission) can set a custom price for shipping via the field shipping price and set a quantity limit per line item (for that order) within the entity variant.  My question is how could I set this up so that each line item (if multiple line items) can have its own shipping rate which is set by the field_shipping_price and then each individual line items shipping price is totaled and the added to the order.  Plus, it checks and then limits the line items quantity per the field_shipping_quantity_limit.

Thanks for any help or direction you can give with this.